# Is Post's correspondence problem recognizable?

Tags: computability, semi-decidability

I want to know whether Post Correspondence Problem (PCP) is recognizable. I learnt how to demonstrate the undecidability of PCP. I thought to use the similar approach for recognizability too i.e. to considering MPCP and show whether it is recognizable. I am not sure if it is a good approach.

Comment: You can not use the approach for showing that something is undecidable for showing that it *is* decidable. Well, that's not *quite* true: you *can* reduce PCP to another recognizable language. That's typically more hassle than describing a recognizer -- just do that.

Comment: @Raphael, no, no hassle at all for some cases.

Comment: @Raphael The question isn't asking to show that PCP is decidable -- it's asking about it being recognizable (recursively enumerable).

Comment: @DavidRicherby True. My first sentence remains true if you replace both instances of "decidable" with "semi-decidable".

Answer (score 7):

We can recognize acceptable inputs of PCP by exhaustively checking all valid possibilities (preferably by non-deterministic TM). *That is it!*. If the input is acceptable then the TM will stop, if it is not then the TM may not stop. Thus PCP is an RE language. [Recognizability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_language) should not be confused with [decidability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_language).

We can do the same with deterministic TM by essentially simulating each thread of NDTM one step at a time.